# MySQL select not in is really slow

Tags: mysql

This is what I have now.

```
SELECT distinct ClientID 
    FROM Table
    WHERE PAmt = '' and ClientID not in 
        (select distinct ClientID from Table where PAmt != '') 
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

ClientID can be inside the Table more then once and some of them have PAmt value some don't.
I am trying to get only the clientid's that never had a PAmt value. The table has about 12000 entry's and only 2700 are unique clientid's

Comment: do you have indexes on ClientID and ID?

Comment: @Fractal: `!=` won't be optimized by a B-Tree index

Comment: hey. is it just me or your and clause pretty much verifies the same thing as the first one? SELECT ClientID where PAmt is empty but not the ClientID where PAmt is not empty..

Answer (score 3):

I think this could be easier solved by

```
SELECT 
  ClientID,
  MAX(IF(PAmt='',0,1)) AS HasPAmt
FROM `Table`
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING HasPAmt=0
```

**Edit**

Some words on the rationale behind this:

Subqueries in MySQL are a beasty thing: If the resultset is either too large (Original SQL) or intertwined with the driving query (@DavidFleeman's answer), the inner query is looped, i.e. it is repeated for every row of the driving query. This ofcourse gives bad performance.

So we try to reformulate the query in a way, that will avoid looping. My suggestion works by running only two queries: The first (everything before the `HAVING`) will create a temp table, that marks each distinct ClientID as having at least one non-empty PAmt (or not), the second selects only those rows of the temp table, that are marked as having none, into the final result set.

Comment: OMG you saved me from a white night. Thank you! Works like a charm :) Now i know how to do it better.

Answer (score 1):

try to reorganize your query to something like this:

```
select clientID
from Table
group by clientID
having max(length(PAmt)) == 0
```

of course you should add index (clientID, PAmt)

if this query will still work slow, add column with pre-calculated length, and replace PAmt with this column

Comment: This one performs better, same speed 0.016s and gave me the right results. 2115 and on Eugen Rieck`s solution i had 2114, probably i have a NULL in there or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try using not exists instead of not in.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/249cd5/26

Answer (score 0):

Take away the subquery:

```
$clientIds = runQuery("select distinct ClientID from Table where PAmt != ''");
$clientIds = implode(",", $clientIds);

runQuery("SELECT distinct ClientID 
FROM Table
WHERE PAmt = '' and ClientID not in 
    ({$clientIds}) 
ORDER BY ID ASC")
```

I know it looks like MySQL should do that optimisation step for you, but it doesn't. You will find your query is about 12000 times faster if you do the sub query as a separate query.